# There is a notification on my lock screen - How do I get rid of it?

Tags: notifications, lock-screen

This morning I awoke to this notification at the bottom on my lock screen of my Nokia Lumia 925, I have no idea where it is coming from and no idea on how to remove it. **Where is this information being pulled from and how can I disable this from happening in the future?**

Picture is my lock screen - message on the bottom underneath the time.
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is probably from Facebook calendar (Facebook Events).

You can prevent events that are not responded by ticking "Only show Facebook events I've responded to" in ***Calendar > Settings***.

If you don't want notification from Calendar at all, go to ***Settings > Lock Screen > Notifications*** and change calendar from options.

Answer (score 1):

That is the Detailed Status shown on the lock screen it is probably coming from the calendar app.  You can change it by going into the Settings app and going into the Lock Screen settings.

This page has screen shots and more information:

http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/windows-phone-8-tip-customize-lock-screen

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this notification at the bottom of your lock screen simply go into settings, then into lock screen. There you will find a subtitle showing "choose app to be shown in more detail" (or something along those lines) click the box under that displaying what your notification links to e.g. Calendar, then select none. You show find your notification goes away.

Answer (score 0):

OPTION IS AVAILABLE IN WINDOWS 10 PHONES INCL LUMIA 640 XL, MAY BE OTHERS ARE ALSO HAVING

You can turn off notification on locked screen like this - Settings > Notification and action > Heading Notification by going down > There are three switches on-off type. The 2nd option is 'show notification on the lock screen' switch IT off.

Now you will neither hear any beap nor the msg will be displayed on locked screen.

Good luck

Comment: This is essentially the same solution as the pre-existing, highest voted answer from over two years ago - what new information did you mean to add?