# How to stop Facebook events from appearing in the calendar?

Tags: 8.1, calendars, facebook

How do I stop Windows Phone 8.1 from automatically syncing with Facebook for calendar events?

Comment: possible duplicate of [There is a notification on my lock screen - How do I get rid of it?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2845/there-is-a-notification-on-my-lock-screen-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it)

Answer (score 3):

Just go in your calendar -> settings. There you can select which calendars should be synced. Just uncheck everything you don't want to see.

Answer (score 2):

1. Turn on Facebook App
2. Go to the Menu (Left-most icon at the top)
3. Scroll to the very bottom and tap on Settings
4. Click on Connect my phone
5. Turn off / on, as desired

Answer (score -1):

Seem to have found an answer, the Facebook app on the phone has a setting which gives the phone permission to sync all the photos, contacts, events etc.

Comment: Can you share where this setting is located?